# Javascript / JSON error: TypeError: myObj is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart with data from a database. I created a PHP-file to put the data into a multidimensional array. This array contains four arrays with five values each. Finally I echo the multidimensional array in the json_encode()-method of PHP.

With my Javascript-file I want to get the JSON, but it is incomplete. I get the first array of the multidimensional array and the first value of the second array.

console.log() tells me there is an error "TypeError: myObj is undefined" in line 12, but I can not find an error in my script.

This is my Javascript:

```js
window.onload=function(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("overviewChart");

        var data = {
            labels: [myObj[0][0], myObj[0][1], myObj[0][2], myObj[0][3], myObj[0][4]],
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 120, 42, 0.7)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 120, 42, 1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(255, 120, 42, 0.9)",
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    label : "Offen",
                    data: [myObj[1][0], myObj[1][1], myObj[1][2], myObj[1][3], myObj[1][4]]
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(50, 255, 50, 0.7)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50, 255, 50, 1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(50, 255, 50, 0.9)",
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    label: "Bestätigt",
                    data: [myObj[2][0], myObj[2][1], myObj[2][2], myObj[2][3], myObj[2][4]]
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 30, 30, 0.8)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 30, 30, 1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(255, 30, 30, 0.9)",
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    label : "Storniert",
                    data: [myObj[3][0], myObj[3][1], myObj[3][2], myObj[3][3], myObj[3][4]]
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I strongly recommend `loop`

Comment: put your code in if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { condition

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. I still get only the first six of 20 values. Only the error message changed. It is now "TypeError: item is undefined" in Chart.js Line 10475, Column: 1

Comment: You did not apply that advice correctly, Markus. You need to put all of the code inside the `if` block, not just the assignment. Don't have any code reference `myObj` when you have not defined it.

Comment: I think I do not understand it. Now my code looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dr0nndsn/

Comment: what is the result of `alert(this.readyState)` and `alert(this.status)` before your if statement?

Answer (score 0):

You only set your myObj variable when this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}
```

However, the rest of the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange function will still run for other readyState values and in those cases myObj will be undefined.

Therefore, the whole function body should be within the if condition:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        var ctx = document.getElementById("overviewChart");

        var data = {
            labels: [myObj[0][0], myObj[0][1], myObj[0][2], myObj[0][3], myObj[0][4]],
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 120, 42, 0.7)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 120, 42, 1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(255, 120, 42, 0.9)",
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    label : "Offen",
                    data: [myObj[1][0], myObj[1][1], myObj[1][2], myObj[1][3], myObj[1][4]]
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(50, 255, 50, 0.7)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50, 255, 50, 1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(50, 255, 50, 0.9)",
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    label: "Bestätigt",
                    data: [myObj[2][0], myObj[2][1], myObj[2][2], myObj[2][3], myObj[2][4]]
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 30, 30, 0.8)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 30, 30, 1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(255, 30, 30, 0.9)",
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    label : "Storniert",
                    data: [myObj[3][0], myObj[3][1], myObj[3][2], myObj[3][3], myObj[3][4]]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Now my code looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dr0nndsn/

But now I do not see anything, the whole chart is not displayed anymore.

Comment: Your 'data' variable is only set inside the if condition. ChartOverview should be initialised inside this condition so that it does not run on other readyState values with no data.

Comment: You could also initialise your chart inside a separate function that exists outside of your 'onreadystatechange' function and that takes the data as a parameter. You could then call that function inside the 'if' condition inside the 'onreadystatechange' function, passing in the data.